# How to solve this indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, fractions

I'm trying to understand how to solve this indefinite integral using the power rule.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} dx &=& \int \frac{x^1}{x^\frac{1}{2}} dx
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Breaking this down

$$
\int x dx = \frac{x^2}{2} + C
$$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int x^\frac{1}{2} dx &=& \frac{x^\frac{3}{2}}{\frac{3}{2}} + C\\
 &=& \frac{2}{3} x^\frac{3}{2} + C
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Wolfram Alpha gives the integral of the original denominator ($\int\sqrt{x} dx$) as the solution. I do not understand what happened to the numerator?

How do I bring the two parts together?

Comment: $$\frac {x}{x^{1/2}} = x^{1-\frac 12} = x^{1/2}$$  So you are looking for $$\int x^{1/2} dx = \frac{x^{3/2}}{3/2} + C = \frac 23 \cdot x^{3/2} +C$$

Comment: There is no simple rule for integrating a product or a quotient. You have to simplify your algebra. What is $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt x}$?

Comment: ${x\over \sqrt x}= \sqrt x$?

Comment: The "power rule" would be $\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$ as used by @amWhy's comment.

Comment: Thank you @amWhy and and Ted thats very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} =  \sqrt{x}$$

$$\int \sqrt{x}\ dx = \frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} + c$$

---

Note that $\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}$ hence when you integrate it, just apply the integration rule for $x^a$.

$$\int x^a\ dx = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} + c ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{for} ~~~ a\neq -1$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can simplify $x\over \sqrt  x$ into just $\sqrt x$. Then integrate:

$$\int \sqrt x \, dx$$

By the reverse power rule.